# OpenCV: cvContourBoundingRect gives "Symbol Not Found" while other contour functions work fine

Tags: opencv, detection, region, contour

NOTE: StackOverflow won't let me answer my own question, so I'm answering it in here. Please scroll to the bottom to see my answer.

QUESTION
Given a binary image, I want to be able to identify which region has the greatest y-coordinate, i.e., which region is the closest to the bottom. In the function below, I try to use contours and bounding rectangles to get the answer I need. However, my use of the function cvContourBOundingRect gives rise to the following error message during compilation:

```
"_cvContourBoundingRectemphasized", referenced from: 
GetLowestContourBoundingRectangle(_IplImage * img, bool) 
in main.o. Symbol(s) not found. Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status. 
Build Failed.
```

This is very strange, since I have successfully used other contour functions like cvFindContours and cvContourArea without any trouble. I tried running some searches on Google, but nothing turned up. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

```
CvRect GetLowestContourBoundingRectangle(IplImage *img, bool invertFlag) {
    // NOTE: CONTOURS ARE DRAWN AROUND WHITE AREAS
    IplImage *output = invertFlag ? cvCloneImage(InvertImage(img)) : cvCloneImage(img); // this goes into find contours and is consequently modified

    // find contours
    CvMemStorage *contourstorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* contours = NULL;
    cvFindContours(output, contourstorage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // analyze each contour
    int lowestRectangleCoordinate = 0;
    CvRect currentBoundingRectangle;
    CvRect lowestBoundingRectangle;

    while (contours) {
        currentBoundingRectangle = cvContourBoundingRect(contours);
        if (currentBoundingRectangle.y + currentBoundingRectangle.height > lowestRectangleCoordinate) {
            lowestRectangleCoordinate = currentBoundingRectangle.y + currentBoundingRectangle.height;
            lowestBoundingRectangle = currentBoundingRectangle;
        }

        contours = contours->h_next;
    }

    cvReleaseMemStorage(&contourstorage);
    return lowestBoundingRectangle;
}
```

ANSWER:
Okay, ironically I found out why it's breaking shortly after drafting my original question (although in fairness I've been wrestling with this for a few hours at this point).

I looked up the header files in which each of the following three functions were defined:

1. cvFindContours -- imgproc_c.h
2. cvContourArea -- imgproc_c.h
3. cvContourBoundingRect -- compat.hpp

compat.hpp is apparently for deprecated functions that are kept around for backwards compatibility. Here's what's written in the header:

```
/*
   A few macros and definitions for backward compatibility
   with the previous versions of OpenCV. They are obsolete and
   are likely to be removed in future. To check whether your code
   uses any of these, define CV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY before
   including cv.h.
*/
```

With that said, does anyone know how I can actually go about writing this function with non-obsolete definitions?

Answer (score 1):

About your original question "OpenCV: cvContourBoundingRect gives “Symbol Not Found”".

The library to use to link with that (deprecated) method is this one:

libopencv_legacy.so

Comment: and the "new one" looks like this one: boundingRect(InputArray points)¶